# Tree Traversal applications

Tags: tree, binary-tree, traversal, inorder, postorder

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knew the question to my practice midterm and understood the answer.

1. In programming, it is often best to copy an existing function that is similar to your new needs, and then alter the copy to suit the new requirements. If I wanted a function to print out a range of numbers in reverse order, which of the four traversals functions would you copy as a basis for the new function?

   Answer: Inorder traversal()
2. Given a binary tree that contains the results of a 64 team single elimination tournament, I want to print out the six teams that F beat. Note the diagram below only shows the upper parts of ht much larger tree. My code only follows the path of F's victories down the root, so it is not a true tree traversal. Nonetheless, which tree traversal code would my code most closely parallel and why? only one or two sentences are needed with 8 points for the correct traversal, and seven points for an explanation of your choice. (I put the image given at the top of my post)

   Answer: Post order traversal because it would have to look at both children first to find the loser and determine the right path to take.

Comment: the first question is suggesting copy-paste and trial-and-error as good software design?!?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by that? Thanks!

Comment: @guido It appears so. I guess that for small code snippets where common parts cannot be factored out, it's a viable option. For larger codebases, there are often opportunities for refactoring, and this practice becomes bad.

Comment: I meant the c&p part. Trial and error is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, if it is on a binary search tree, then in-order traversal would give you a sorted list of values. So if you are looking for values within a given range, it would be best to use in-order traversal.

For question 2, since it is representing a tournament, the tree is built in a bottom-up approach, which is post-order. We also know that F has to be in a leaf, so post-order is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Let us understand In-order and Post-order traversals first:

In-Order traversal: This traversal gives a sorted array, in an increasing order. Algorithm:

```
   1. Traverse left-subtree
   2. Visit Root
   3. Traverse right-subtree
```

Post-Order traversal: Post-order traversal is generally used in deleting a tree. The algorithm is as follows:

```
   1. Traverse left-subtree
   2. Traverse right-subtree
   3. Visit Root
```

Answer 1: In order traversal results in a sorted array of values.
Answer 2: Post order traversal would be the right choice for this, because it will check both the children nodes, and if F is found, that path will be followed. Furthermore, F will be a eventually be a leaf node, due to this post-order becomes a good choice.